# How would you go about creating a RealityKit anchor for a statue in a church?

Tags: ios, realitykit

When developing an AR app (in my case, for iOS with RealityKit), what would be a good strategy for creating an anchor on a large statue that stands on an altar in a church (in order to place some explanatory text and links on it)?

- The statue is, of course, three-dimensional (i.e. an Image Anchor would not be appropriate)
- The statue is not in front of a plain surface (it is on a richly decorated baroque altar), which does not seem to be the recommended use case for Object Capture
- The statue is not accessible from every angle (it is placed high up, so with a standard tripod, you can only photograph it from below, and you cannot go behind it. App users will have the same view constraints though, so it is not really necessary to detect those parts of the object that you can never see).